# How to autodocument graphql query in graphene-django?

Tags: graphene-python, graphene-django

With graphene-django when documenting e.g. GraphQL object type classes the docstrings are usually used to autogenerate documentation which is visible in GraphiQL. This should also work with plain graphene-python and all graphene-python based implementations like graphene and graphene-mongo as well. But the docstrings used for resolver functions of queries is not used to autodocument Queries. How can I document queries with docstrings?